# I want to use Dirac delta as function of time in a python code to solve four coupled differential equation. I am not getting it right

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations, odeint

I want to use  Dirac delta as function of time in a python code to solve four coupled
differential equation. In the python code i am using solve_ivp to solve the coupled equation.
I am not getting it right. I am not able to define the Dirac delta function. Please help me if
anyone can. In the python code i am using solve_ivp to solve the coupled equation.
I am not getting it right. I am not able to define the Dirac delta function. Please help me if
anyone can.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate
from pylab import *
from qutip import *
import scipy.special as sp
import scipy.linalg as la
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import math
import cmath

from sympy import DiracDelta, diff, pi
from scipy import signal
omg1 = 1
omg2 = 1.1
Omg=1
Omegar=10
beta=0.1
Mu=0.5
epsilon=0.01
V=1
K=0.5
g=1
m=1
hcut =1
A = 0.001
p = [ omg1, omg2, Omg,Omegar, beta, Mu, K, g,m]
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#####----------------Initial conditions, packed in w0--------------------------
##### IMPORTANT NOTE:
#####   Please feed initial values with a complex part even if it's zero

#y1 & y2 are first derivatives of x1 and x2
x1 = 1
x2 = 0


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
z1 = 0+0j
z2 = 1+0j
#A  = 0

w0 = [x1, x2,z1,z2]
####----------------Function model passed to the ode solver--------------------
def f(t):
    result = 0
    for i in range(-25,25,1):
        result = result + 1.0*DiracDelta(t-(i+1)*2*np.pi)
    
def vectorfield(t, w, omg1, omg2,Omg,Omegar, beta,Mu,K,g,m):
    
    x1, x2,z1,z2= w
    #result = 0
    #for i in range(-10,10,1):
    #    result = result + 1.0*DiracDelta(t-(i+1)*np.pi)

    field = [((g*np.sqrt(2*(x1)/(m*Omegar))*np.sin(x2))*(-0.5* abs(z2)**2 * np.cos(np.pi/3) + 0.5* np.conj(z1)* z2* np.sin(np.pi/3) + 0.5*
               abs(z1)**2*np.cos(np.pi/3) + 0.5* np.conj(z2)* z1* np.sin(np.pi/3))-K*np.sin(x2)*f(t)),
             ((-g/np.sqrt((2*(x1)*m*Omegar))*np.cos(x2))*(-0.5* abs(z2)**2 * np.cos(np.pi/3) + 0.5* np.conj(z1)* z2* np.sin(np.pi/3) + 0.5*
               abs(z1)**2*np.cos(np.pi/3) + 0.5* np.conj(z2)* z1* np.sin(np.pi/3))+x1),
             ((z1*(0.5*Omg+0.5*g*np.sqrt(2*x1/(m*Omegar))*np.cos(x2)*np.cos(np.pi/3))+0.5*z2*g*np.sqrt(2*x1/         (m*Omegar))*np.cos(x2)*np.sin(np.pi/3)) * -1j * (1/hcut) * (1/(cmath.sqrt(abs(z1)**2 + abs(z2)**2 )))),
             (( z2*(-0.5*Omg+0.5*g*np.sqrt(2*x1/(m*Omegar))*np.cos(x2)*np.cos(np.pi/3))+  0.5*g*np.sqrt(2*x1/(m*Omegar))*np.cos(x2)*z1*np.sin(np.pi/3)) * -1j * (1/hcut) * (1/(cmath.sqrt(abs(z1)**2 + abs(z2)**2 ))))]
              
    
    #field1 = np.array(field, dtype='complex_')
    #print(abs(z1)**2 + abs(z2)**2 )
    print(z2)
    return field


duration = 50
#   time points
t = np.linspace(0, duration, 100) 
abserr = 1.0e-10
relerr = 1.0e-6
#solution = odeint(vectorfield, w0, t, args=(p,)) 
solution = solve_ivp(vectorfield, [0, duration], w0,t_eval=t ,args=(p),  atol=abserr, 
rtol=relerr)

lw = 1
#'''
plot1 = plt.figure(1)
plt.style.use('seaborn-darkgrid')

plt.xlabel('time(t)')
plt.grid(True)

####----------------Plotting the oscillator dynamics---------------------------
plt.plot(t, solution.y[0,:], 'b', label='I', linewidth=lw)
plt.plot(t, solution.y[1,:], 'r', label='$\Theta$', linewidth=lw)
plt.plot(t, solution.y[2,:], 'g', label='x1(t)', linewidth=lw)
plt.plot(t, solution.y[3,:], 'orange', label='x2(t)', linewidth=lw)

plt.legend()

expect_1 = np.absolute(solution.y[2,:])**2 -  np.absolute(solution.y[3,:])**2 

plot2 = plt.figure(2)
plt.xlabel('time(t)')

#plt.plot(t, result, 'm', label='z_expect2', linewidth=lw)
plt.plot(t, solution.y[0,:], 'b', label='I', linewidth=lw)

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please make a minimal example that demonstrates what kind of effect you want to achieve. Also, consult your sources, the Dirac delta is a distribution, a functional on a function space. At most it can be interpreted as the mass density of a point mass. It never is an ordinary function. You will need to simulate the effect of delta by interrupting the integration and manually inserting the jump in the appropriate components.

Comment: Dear Sir,  Yes, I exactly needs this what you said but I don't know how to do it I have Dirac delta in the code F(t)  will denote as kick for the equation when (t= 2*n *Pi) .( You will need to simulate the effect of delta by interrupting the integration and manually inserting the jump in the appropriate components.)

Comment: I see a call to `DiracDelta` in `f`, but don't see any kind of definition or import.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63230568/numerical-solution-to-a-differential-equation-containing-a-dirac-delta, I have put two variants to deal with the delta in a new answer. The ODE there is minimal, but the deltas might not be in a place where you would need them.